# Tacit function composition in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, composition, tacit-programming, pointfree

Say I have a `mean` function defined like so:

```
mean xs = sum xs / (fromIntegral $ length xs)
```

but I want it in some tacit form, like this:

```
mean = sum / (fromIntegral . length)
```

Is there a built-in Haskell way to do something along these lines without having to build up my own `tacit` function (something like this):

```
tacit :: (a -> b -> c) -> (d -> a) -> (d -> b) -> d -> c
tacit a b c i = a (b i) (c i)
```

In this form, the function looks like this:

```
mean = tacit (/) sum (fromIntegral . length)
```

but it feels like there might be a way to avoid having to use an explicit function such as this. I'm just wondering; is there some way to do this that is built in to Haskell?

Comment: See http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html, http://conal.net/blog/posts/more-beautiful-fold-zipping

Comment: The technical term for what you call "tacit" is "point free" (or sometimes "pointless" for people being sarcastic). The term "point" comes from topology, and it actually refers to the variables.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, "tacit" is the term used by the J programming language (and maybe others?) to refer to what is more commonly known as "point free".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Applicative functors work pretty well here.

```
import Control.Applicative

mean = (/) <$> sum <*> (fromIntegral . length)
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes, your `tacit` function is `liftM2` in the `(->) r` monad (`liftM2` is in `Control.Monad`, and the function instance of Monad is in `Control.Monad.Instances`).

I found this using the `pointfree` program (you can install it via `cabal install pointfree`), invoked as:

```
$ pointfree '\xs -> sum xs / (fromIntegral $ length xs)'
```

(in a Unix terminal)

Comment: And then you can make a `Num` instance for `(->) r` and then `mean = sum / (fromIntegral . length)` will actually work.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: you need `Fractional` too because of `(/)`.  Just tried it and confirmed that's all you need.

Comment: And an amusing addition to that is that once you have the `Num r => Num (a -> r)` instance, you can add addition to itself: `(+) + (+)` becomes a well-typed expression (equivalent to `\x y -> (x + y) + (x + y)`).

Comment: @sacundim Ah, right. And `1 2 3 4` is also a well-typed expression. It's clear why this is not a built-in instance.

Comment: Heh, I didn't think of that one. But what makes it worse is that if a module of yours imports any module that uses this instance directly or indirectly, you're going to get this instance. So one should really wrap it with a `newtype`—in which case the extra syntactic overhead means that you might as well use `Applicative`.

Comment: @Sjored, OK, I give in, what does 1 2 3 4 give you?

Comment: @PaulJohnson, `1`, assuming `fromIntegral = const . fromIntegral`.

Comment: As the maintainer of pointfree, I ought to point out (no pun intended) that most of the testsuite currently fails (has been doing so since before I inherited it, I might add!)