# Numbers as multiplicative functions (weird but entertaining)

Tags: haskell

In the comments of the question [Tacit function composition in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061176/tacit-function-composition-in-haskell), people mentioned making a `Num` instance for `a -> r`, so I thought I'd play with using function notation to represent multiplication:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Control.Applicative

instance Show (a->r) where   -- not needed in recent GHC versions
  show f = " a function "

instance Eq (a->r) where     -- not needed in recent GHC versions
  f == g = error "sorry, Haskell, I lied, I can't really compare functions for equality"

instance (Num r,a~r) => Num (a -> r) where
  (+) = liftA2 (+)
  (-) = liftA2 (-)
  (*) = liftA2 (*)
  abs = liftA abs
  negate = liftA negate
  signum = liftA signum
  fromInteger a = (fromInteger a *)
```

Note that the fromInteger definition means I can write `3 4` which evaluates to 12, and `7 (2+8)` is 70, just as you'd hope.

Then it all goes wonderfully, entertainingly weird! Please explain this wierdness if you can:

```
*Main> 1 2 3
18
*Main> 1 2 4
32
*Main> 1 2 5
50
*Main> 2 2 3
36
*Main> 2 2 4
64
*Main> 2 2 5
100
*Main> (2 3) (5 2)
600
```

[Edit: used Applicative instead of Monad because Applicative is great generally, but it doesn't make much difference at all to the code.]

Comment: In GHC 7.4, it is possible to remove the dummy `Show` and `Eq` instances, as `Num` no longer requires them.

Comment: `Monad` is overkill here. The simpler & more general `Applicative` suffices.

Comment: @sdcvvc I'll be upgrading sometime soon, yes.

Comment: @Conal You're very right. Applicative is much nicer, I was just mindlessly using the Classes from the original context. I understood the answer below when I saw `liftM2 (*) (2*) (3*)` because I thought of that as `(*) <$> (2*) <*> (3*)`, which makes sense. [Thanks for your work which led me to the wonderfully functional Applicative world. I still remember clearly when I first read Philip Wadler's _The essence of functional programming_, and I had a similar moment of revelation when reading your work on tangible values: _this_ is what UI should be like in fp, _this_ is what Applicative means.]

Comment: @Conal I've edited it now to use Applicative. It's surprising how much easier it feels conceptually now, with almost no change at all to the code!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In an expression like `2 3 4` with your instances, both `2` and `3` are functions. So `2` is actually `(2 *)` and has a type `Num a => a -> a`. `3` is the same. `2 3` is then `(2 *) (3 *)` which is the same as `2 * (3 *)`. By your instance, this is `liftM2 (*) 2 (3 *)`  which is then `liftM2 (*) (2 *) (3 *)`. Now this expression works without any of your instances.

So what does this mean? Well, `liftM2` for functions is a sort of double composition. In particular, `liftM2 f g h` is the same as `\ x -> f (g x) (h x)`. So `liftM2 (*) (2 *) (3 *)` is then `\ x -> (*) ((2 *) x) ((3 *) x)`. Simplifying a bit, we get: `\ x -> (2 * x) * (3 * x)`. So now we know that `2 3 4` is actually `(2 * 4) * (3 * 4)`.

Now then, why does `liftM2` for functions work this way? Let's look at the monad instance for `(->) r` (keep in mind that `(->) r` is `(r ->)` but we can't write type-level operator sections):

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where  
    return x = \_ -> x  
    h >>= f = \w -> f (h w) w
```

So `return` is `const`. `>>=` is a little weird. I think it's easier to see this in terms of `join`. For functions, `join` works like this:

```
join f = \ x -> f x x
```

That is, it takes a function of two arguments and turns it into a function of one argument by using that argument twice. Simple enough. This definition also makes sense. For functions, `join` has to turn a function of two arguments into a function of one; the only reasonable way to do this is to use that one argument twice.

`>>=` is `fmap` followed by `join`. For functions, `fmap` is just `(.)`. So now `>>=` is equal to:

```
h >>= f = join (f . h)
```

which is just:

```
h >>= f = \ x -> (f . h) x x
```

now we just get rid of `.` to get:

```
h >>= f = \ x -> f (h x) x
```

So now that we know how `>>=` works, we can look at `liftM2`. `liftM2` is defined as follows:

```
liftM2 f a b = a >>= \ a' -> b >>= \ b' -> return (f a' b')
```

We can simply this bit by bit. First, `return (f a' b')` turns into `\ _ -> f a' b'`. Combined with the `\ b' ->`, we get: `\ b' _ -> f a' b'`. Then `b >>= \ b' _ -> f a' b'` turns into:

```
 \ x -> (\ b' _ -> f a' b') (b x) x
```

since the second `x` is ignored, we get: `\ x -> (\ b' -> f a' b') (b x)` which is then reduced to `\ x -> f a' (b x)`. So this leaves us with:

```
a >>= \ a' -> \ x -> f a' (b x)
```

Again, we substitute `>>=`:

```
\ y -> (\ a' x -> f a' (b x)) (a y) y
```

this reduces to:

```
 \ y -> f (a y) (b y)
```

which is exactly what we used as `liftM2` earlier!

Hopefully now the behavior of `2 3 4` makes sense completely.

Comment: Ah yes - as soon as you got to `liftM2 (*) (2 *) (3 *)  4` I saw why it was squaring the last argument - this just means `(+) $ (2*) 4 $ (3*) 4`. And `(2 3) (5 2)` has unnecessary brackets, so it's just `2 4 (5 2)` and is 300 for the same reason.

Comment: By the way, I'm happy with the Applicative and Monad instances for `(->) r` and should have said so in the question, it's just my brain just started leaking out of my ears when I did `2 3 4`, and I didn't even try to hand-evaluate. doh! Your explanation will make it far clearer for others though, so thanks also.

Comment: @AndrewC: I just wrote down my thought process from when I was figuring out exactly what `2 3 4` did, so it was helping myself as much as anybody else :P.