# Making numeric functions an instance of Num?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I want to be able to compose numeric functions in haskell using binary operators. So, for example, with unary numeric functions:

```
f*g
```

should translate to:

```
\x -> (f x)*(g x)
```

and similarly for addition. Making your own operator to do this is pretty straightforward, but I'd really like to just make `Num a => a -> a` functions an instance of Num, but I'm not sure how to do so.

I'd also like to make this arity generic, but that might be too much trouble for how difficult it is to do arity generic functions in Haskell, so it might just be better to define seperate `Num a => a -> a -> a`, `Num a => a -> a -> a -> a`, etc... instances up to some reasonably large number.

Comment: If you define an instance of `Num` for `Num a, Num b => a -> b` you won't have to worry about instances for multiple arities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

an instance with generic arity

```
instance Num b => Num (a->b) where
    f + g = \x -> f x + g x
    f - g = \x -> f x - g x
    f * g = \x -> f x * g x
    negate f = negate . f
    abs f = abs . f
    signum f = signum . f
    fromInteger n = \x -> fromInteger n
```

Edit: As Christian Conkle points out, there are problems with this approach. If you plan to use these instances for anything important or just want to understand the issues, you should read the resources he provided and decide for yourself whether this fits your needs. My intention was to provide an easy way to play with numeric functions using natural notation with as simple an implementation as possible.

Comment: The constraint on `a` is unnecessary, particularly for the stated purpose of allowing arbitrary arity. Indeed, it makes it *less* flexible than without: you can't compose two functions of type `String -> Int`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Having thought about it further, I'm increasingly convinced that this approach is deeply flawed. If you're doing so much arithmetic that this reduces line noise compared to using `Applicative`, it seems like the danger of confusion and/or using `fromIntegral` accidentally would be too great.

Comment: @ChristianConkle The bit about orphan instances is worrying, but if you're worried about accidentally using `fromIntegral` just add a more recognizable function like `toFunc = fromInteger`

Comment: That's not the concern. The concern is that the compiler uses `fromInteger` to resolve *all* integer literals. Now all of a sudden the compiler will start inferring `2 :: Num b => a -> b`, which will likely cause wrong behavior and/or incomprehensible errors.

Comment: I would like to point out that if you look at the source for the NumInstances package, the code is exactly the same as what I provided, except that they use some abstractions (that are equivalent) which I thought would only obfuscate it. I can agree that in most cases a `Num` instance is not the best way to handle operations on functions, but it's what the OP asked for, so I provided one.

Answer (score 15):

### The idiomatic approach

There is an instance of `Applicative` for `(->) a`, which means that *all* functions are applicative functors. The modern idiom for composing *any* functions in the way you're describing is to use `Applicative`, like this:

```
(*) <$> f <*> g
liftA2 (*) f g -- these two are equivalent
```

This makes the operation clear. Both of these approaches are slightly more verbose but seem to me to express the combination pattern far more clearly.

Furthermore, this is a far more general approach. If you understand this idiom, you will be able to apply it in many other contexts than just `Num`. If you're not familiar with `Applicative`, one place to start is the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Applicative). If you're theoretically inclined, you may check [McBride and Patterson's famous article](http://strictlypositive.org/IdiomLite.pdf). (For the record, I'm using "idiom" here in the ordinary sense, but mindful of the pun.)

### `Num b => Num (a -> b)`

The instance you want (and others besides) is available in the [NumInstances package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumInstances). You can copy out the instance @genisage posted; they're functionally identical. (@genisage wrote it out more explicitly; comparing the two implementations may be enlightening.) Importing the library on Hackage has the benefit of highlighting for other developers that you're using an orphan instance.

There's a problem with `Num b => Num (a -> b)`, however. In short, `2` is now not only a number but also a function with an infinite number of arguments, all of which it ignores. `2 (3 + 4)` now equals `2`. Any use of an integer literal as a function will almost certainly give an unexpected and incorrect result, and there's no way to warn the programmer short of a runtime exception.

As spelled out in the [2010 Haskell Report section 6.4.1](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1), "An integer literal represents the application of the function `fromInteger` to the appropriate value of type `Integer`." This means writing `2` or `12345` in your source code or in GHCi is equivalent to writing `fromInteger 2` or `fromInteger 12345`. Either expression therefore has type `Num a => a`.

As a result, `fromInteger` is absolutely *pervasive* in Haskell. Normally this works out wonderfully; when you write a number in your source code, you get a number--of the appropriate type. But with your `Num` instance for functions, the type of `fromInteger 2` could very well be `a -> Integer` or `a -> b -> Integer`. In fact, GHC will happily replace the literal `2` with a function, not a number--and a particularly dangerous function too, one that discards any data given to it. (`fromInteger n = \_ -> n` or `const n`; i.e. throw out all arguments and just give `n`.)

Often you can get away with not implementing inapplicable class members, or by implementing them with `undefined`, either of which gives a runtime error. This is, for the same reasons, not a fix to the present problem.

### A more sensible instance: pseudo-`Num a => Num (a -> a)`

If you're willing to restrict yourself to multiplying and adding unary functions of type `Num a => a -> a`, we can ameliorate the `fromInteger` problem a bit, or at least have `2 (3 + 5)` equal `16` rather than `2`. The answer is simply to define `fromInteger 3` as `(*) 3` rather than `const 3`:

```
instance (a ~ b, Num a) => Num (a -> b) where
  fromInteger = (*) . fromInteger
  negate      = fmap negate
  (+)         = liftA2 (+)
  (*)         = liftA2 (*)
  abs         = fmap abs
  signum      = fmap signum
```

```
ghci> 2 (3 + 4)
14
ghci> let x = 2 ((2 *) + (3 *))
ghci> :t x
x :: Num a => a -> a
ghci> x 1
10
ghci> x 2
40
```

Note that although this is perhaps morally equivalent to `Num a => Num (a -> a)`, it has to be defined with the equality constraint (which requires `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies`). Otherwise we'll get an ambiguity error for something like `(2 3) :: Int`. I'm not up to explaining why, sorry. Basically, the equality constraint `a ~ b => a -> b` allows the inferred or stated type of `b` to propagate to `a` during inference.

For a nice explanation of why and how this instance works, see the answer to [Numbers as multiplicative functions (weird but entertaining)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133932/numbers-as-multiplicative-functions-weird-but-entertaining).

### Orphan instance warning

Do not expose any module that contains--or imports a module that contains--or imports a module that imports a module that contains...--either of these instances without understanding the problem of [orphan instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance) and/or warning your users accordingly.

Comment: It seems like the tail is wagging the dog here. It is very common in mathematics to define the arithmetic operators point wise on functions and other structures.

Comment: The second encoding doesn't work as one might expect: `2 3 5` evaluates to `(\n -> (2 * n) * (3 * n)) 5` and hence equals `150` instead of `30`.