# Understanding the Haskell type system in the context of applicatives

Tags: haskell, type-systems, applicative

I am playing with `Control.Applicative` and I am realizing I don't understand everything with the Haskell type system.

Here is my experiment in Ghci:

```
λ :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

λ :t (<*>) (pure 2)
(<*>) (pure 2) :: (Num (a -> b), Applicative f) => f a -> f b
```

The type of the first argument of `<*>` is `f (a -> b)`.

- Why is this expression correct?
- How can it be unified with `(pure 2)` since the constant `2` is not of type `a -> b`?
- What does `Num (a -> b)` mean? How can a function having a `a -> b` type be an instance of `Num`?

Comment: `Num (a -> b)` in the context doesn't mean there *is* a `Num` instance for `a -> b`.  It means "if there *were*" a `Num` instance for `a -> b` then the expression would have this type.

Comment: In addition, the "constant" is a literal, and therefore has type `2 :: Num a => a`.

Comment: try next: `:t (<*>) (pure (2 :: Int))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument of `<*>` is supposed to be `f (a -> b)`. So given `(<*>) (pure x)`, this is well-typed provided that `x` is some kind of function.

The type of `2` is `Num a => a`. In other words, `2` can be *any possible type*, so long as it's an instance of `Num`.

So in your expression `(<*>) (pure 2)`, this is well-typed provided that the type of `2` is a function type, and that function type has a `Num` instance.

Of course, there is almost no reason why you would ever want a function to have a `Num` instance. But the compiler doesn't know that. All it's saying is that *if* there was such an instance, then the expression would become well-typed.

(This is similar to the error you sometimes see where the compiler wants some type to be an instance of `Integral` and `Fractional` simultaneously. To a human, this is a nonsensical combination. To a machine, they're just two ordinary classes...)

Comment: Having functions behave like numbers is actually quite useful sometimes.  It's not a standard instance, but it makes perfect sense.  Something like `instance (Num b) => Num (a -> b) where f + g = \ x -> f x + f y` etc.  This allows you to write things like `(sin + cos) 0.1` with the obvious meaning.

Comment: How could be ```2``` be of a function type? How would you call it? Are number literals part of the Num class per definition?

Comment: @augustss I did say "almost". ;-)

Comment: Remember, `2` is just syntax for some instance of Num which is how you can treat it as Int or Double with abandon. In the case of `Num b => Num (a -> b)`, 2 becomes the function which is "constantly 2", or `const 2`.

Comment: Thanks. May you refer me to a doc or spec explaining that in details? I would never have thought it would be interpreted as ```const 2```

Comment: It isn't by default, but it is acceptable (read: law-abiding) to do so. The fragment of code augustss gave above is a valid (if partial) `instance Num b => Num (a -> b)`. The relevant part you're asking for would look like `fromInteger a = const (fromInteger a)`. In relation to `Applicative`s you can see this as nothing more than lifting the `Num` methods into the `Reader` `Applicative`, `type Reader a b = (a -> b)`. For instance, `fromInteger a = pure (fromInteger a)` and `(+) = liftA2 (+)`.

Comment: @z1naOK9nu8iY5A Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515102/making-numeric-functions-an-instance-of-num

Comment: @z1naOK9nu8iY5A Also, https://gist.github.com/tel/e1f040a4e42887e6ab7a to clarify that `Applicative` nonsense I was talking about in my previous comment.