# Understanding type of `5 1`

Tags: haskell, types

I used this Haskell interpreter right here: https://tryhaskell.org/

When I provided the input `5 1` it tells me - I assume it is the type - that the expression is of type `(Num a, Num (a -> t)) => t`:

```
λ 5 1
:: (Num a, Num (a -> t)) => t
```

Now I have tried to understand how to interpret this and this is what I came up with.

`a` is any `Num` type and so is `a -> t`. The expression results in some type `t` that is produced by theoretically applying `1` (type `a`) to `5` (type `a -> t`).

This really disturbs me because I don't see how the constraint `Num (a -> t)` makes sense. Theoretically it looks to be the correct interpretation but I can't find prove for that.

---

#### The interpretation is correct

It makes sense because `Num` is a polymorphic type - which can be a function.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the interpreter, this code should not parse.

Comment: @Eric This is not a bug in the interpreter, this code can actually be used for practical purposes.  Probably not a good idea, but it can be done.

Comment: I get http://pastebin.com/zRyi1PyR

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515102/making-numeric-functions-an-instance-of-num

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numerals are polymorphic in Haskell.  When you write something like

```
5
```

The compiler turns this into `fromInteger (5 :: Integer) :: Num a => a`.  The compiler doesn't know beforehand what instance to use, so it'll do it's best to guess from context.  If you have `5 1`, then the first numeral is a polymorphic `Num` type, that also must be a function.  The second numeral is just seen as a `Num`, so this is quite normal.

But you may ask "How can a number be a function?"  If everything in the world made sense, then numbers wouldn't be functions, but you can actually write an instance for them that behaves, more or less:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Num a => Num (a -> a) where
    fromInteger a = const (fromInteger a)
    a + b = \c -> a c + b c
    a * b = \c -> a c * b c
    abs a = \c -> abs (a c)
    signum a = \c -> signum (a c)
    negate a = \c -> negate (a c)
```

This satisfies the definition, but it probably wouldn't be very useful.  For example:

```
> let x = 1 :: Int -> Int; y = 2 :: Int -> Int
> x + y $ 0
3
> x + y $ 102089
3
> x + y $ undefined
3
```

So here, the argument does not matter to the expression, it's not even evaluated.  How about a more interesting one:

```
> let x = (+10); y = (*10)
> x + y $ 0    -- x 0 + y 0 = 0 + 10 + 0 * 10
10
> x + y $ 1    -- x 1 + y 1 = 1 + 10 + 1 * 10
21
> x + y $ 2
32
```

And so forth.  I'm sure someone can find an interesting use case for it, but I wouldn't recommend it, it's quite clearly not very intuitive.

Comment: Defining a `Num` instance directly on function types is indeed confusing and poor practice, but such an instance can be useful on a `newtype` wrapper over them. I was once prototyping a system for defining business calculations, that allowed you to say stuff like `monthlyGoal = (shift (monthDuration (-1)) monthlySales) * 1.05`, where the prototype of `montlyGoal, monthlySales :: Metric (Year, Month) Decimal` was a newtype wrapper around `(Year, Month) -> Decimal`. In this case `1.05 :: Metric (Year, Month) Decimal` is the metric whose value is 1.05 at all year/month combinations.

Comment: It doesn't make sense when you indeed only deal with const function and evaluate them directly, but it's nice to be able to add constant ex : `let x = (*10) :: Int -> Int` then `let y = x+1`, and finaly `y 3 => 31`

Comment: If you make the instance for `b -> a` it's more general and requires no language extensions.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, numbers are polymorphic:

```
λ> :t 5
5 :: Num a => a
```

The *important* thing to note here is that function application in Haskell is *whitespace*. So to make something like `5 2` typecheck, all you have to do is create an instance for `(a -> a)` type.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct.

> I don't see how the constraint Num (a -> t) makes sense.

The key here is that anything can be a `Num` type, as long as somewhere in your code you have an instance declaration for it. So if for some `a` and `t` (with `a` being a `Num` type), you wrote `instance Num (a -> t) where ...`, then `a -> t` would be a `Num` type and `5 1` could actually be evaluated to a value.